# How to finish this very easy distributed training example?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow version 0.12.1, and following [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).

What I want to do is to add 1 to `count` in every worker.

My goal is to print results that are >`1`, but I'm only getting `1`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('job_name', '', '')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('ps_hosts', '','')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('worker_hosts', '','')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('task_index', 0, '')

ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(',')
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(',')
cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec({'ps': ps_hosts,'worker': worker_hosts})
server = tf.train.Server(
                    {'ps': ps_hosts,'worker': worker_hosts},
                    job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                    task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

if FLAGS.job_name == 'ps':
  server.join()

with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
               worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
               cluster=cluster_spec)):
  count = tf.Variable(0)
  count = tf.add(count,tf.constant(1))
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                            logdir="./checkpoint/",
                            init_op=init,
                            summary_op=None,
                            saver=None,
                            global_step=None,
                            save_model_secs=60)

with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    while step <= 999999999:
        result = sess.run(count)
        if step%10000 == 0:
          print(result)
        if result>=2:
          print("!!!!!!!!")
        step += 1
    print("Finished!")

sv.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually independent of distributed execution, and stems from these two lines:

```
  count = tf.Variable(0)
  count = tf.add(count,tf.constant(1))
```

The [`tf.add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add) op is a pure functional op, which creates a new tensor with its output each time it runs, rather than modifying its input. If you want the value to increase, and that increase to be visible across workers, you must use the [`tf.Variable.assign_add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign_add) method instead, as follows:

```
  count = tf.Variable(0)
  increment_count = count.assign_add(1)
```

Then call `sess.run(increment_count)` inside your training loop to increment the value of the `count` variable.